# How to find most used phrases in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, facet

I know that you can find most used terms in an index with using facets.

For example on following inputs:

```
"A B C" 
"AA BB CC"
"A AA B BB"
"AA B"
```

term facet returns this:

```
B:3
AA:3
A:2
BB:2
CC:1
C:1
```

But I'm wondering that is it possible to list followings:

```
AA B:2
A B:1
BB CC:1

....etc...
```

Is there such a feature in ElasticSearch?

Comment: Maybe try define a custom analyzer on the field which uses the `shingle` analyzer. This will create tokens by combining words (like you are asking). You can then try to see if the facet will return counts on these combined tokens. Have a [look at the es docs on shingle token filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/analysis/shingle-tokenfilter/)

Comment: Thanks, this might work. Facets returns tokens, so most probably it will return these phrase_tokens also.

But, this is not applicable for existing indexes and this will increases file size too much,right?. 

I will need this feature for on 5GB of my data everyday. And after that day ends I'll no longer need it. So, I guess best thing to do index that 5GB of data at the end of everyday, store the facet results and then delete that new index data. (This will go on in a loop) Any other options?

Comment: I believe answer is available at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39380463/get-top-100-most-used-three-word-phrases-in-all-documents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in ramseykhalaf's comment, a shingle filter would produce tokens of length "n" words.

```
"settings" : { 
   "analysis" : {
       "filter" : {
          "shingle":{
              "type":"shingle",
              "max_shingle_size":5,
              "min_shingle_size":2,
              "output_unigrams":"true"
           },
           "filter_stop":{
              "type":"stop",
              "enable_position_increments":"false"
           }
       },
       "analyzer" : {
           "shingle_analyzer" : {
               "type" : "custom",
               "tokenizer" : "whitespace",
               "filter" : ["standard," "lowercase", "shingle", "filter_stop"]
           }
       }
   }
},
"mappings" : {
   "type" : {
       "properties" : {
           "letters" : {
               "type" : "string",
               "analyzer" : "shingle_analyzer"
           }
       }
   }
}
```

See this [blog post](http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/searching-with-shingles/) for full details.

Comment: i added the shingles, and i think it is working, but http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/searching-with-shingles/still does not allow me to find out what are the most used phrases. how do we use a facet and shingles, http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-facets-terms-stats-facet.html, i still get one word result, "{term: term1, count: 203}", how do i get "{term: "shingles is": count 5}"?

Comment: I have the same problems - I haven't tried this yet - but if you do the aggregation/faceting on the shingled field does that help?.  I'm just not sure about the stemming in the analysis.  eg, If I have "water hole" and "watering hole" and "watered hole"  those would stem to the same but maybe they shouldn't.  http://project.carrot2.org/index.html is really made for this - but if you could do it in elastic search alone that would be great.

Comment: Terms and Significant terms aggregation are not working with shingled tokens. Don't know why yet.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if elasticsearch will let you do this the way you want natively.  But you might be interested in checking out Carrot2 - http://search.carrot2.org  to accomplished what you want (and probably more.)

Comment: the current url to carrot2 is https://search.carrot2.org/