# Elasticsearch Search Keyword Inside A Larger Text

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm kind of new to Elasticsearch. 
I'm storing a lot of keywords inside Elasticsearch, something like

```
{"text": "harry potter", "added": "2013-11-10"}
{"text": "prisoner of azkaban", "added": "2013-11-10"}
...
```

What I want to do is, given a larger text, find all keywords that occur in that string.

For example, for string `harry potter and the prisoner of azkaban`, I most likely expect to have `harry potter` and `prisoner of azkaban` leaving `and the` as the remainder.

My algorithm is

```
1. search the keyword with the best score for the input
2. if found, remove the keyword inside the input. otherwise exit.
3. go back to step 1 and use the remainder as the input.
```

I initially use this query

```
{
   "query": {
       "match": {
           "text": "harry potter and prisoner of azkaban"
       }
   }
}
```

This most likely return `prisoner of azkaban` in the first pass and `harry potter` after that.

For most text inputs I have, this work nicely. But then I notice for some text inputs, I don't get what I expect because of the scoring. There are some keywords that have better scoring than the other but don't really exist in the input.

For example, in one case, there is a keyword `prisoner harry potter`. When I try the query using `harry potter and prisoner of azkaban`, this keyword has (let's just assume for the sake of example) the best score than `harry potter` and the `prisoner of azkaban`, but I can not remove the keyword inside the input because of the order.

Well, I can modify the algorithm to

```
1. search the 5 keywords with the best score for the input
2. for each keywords check against the input, 
      if a keyword inside the input remove it from the input.
3. if at least one keyword is inside the input go back to step 1
      and use the remainder as the new input otherwise exit.
```

But I'm wondering if there is another way to modify, maybe the query, or maybe the analyzer, or maybe the mapping to improve the scoring.

.. or maybe Elasticsearch is not suitable for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [shingle indexing](http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/searching-with-shingles/) then search with one query for once, without using any algorithms.

Shingle analyzer basicly seperates your text into terms and term groups.

```
Text : I love apple
Terms: I, love, apple, I love, love apple, I love apple
```

The use following query to match all documents.

```
{
   "query": {
       "match": {
           "text": "harry potter and prisoner of azkaban"
       }
   }
}
```

[Also here an answer to my question about shingle analyzer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18252549/how-to-find-most-used-phrases-in-elasticsearch)

Comment: thanks for the answer. i just tried here https://gist.github.com/petrabarus/f7cc8c6df312a69cf701. but the result still returning something like `harry and potter`, `prisoner harry potter`. i was hoping something like `harry potter` and `prisoner of azkaban` get better scoring.

Comment: turns out, i need to change the `index_analyzer` to `keyword` and it works just like what i wanted.