# Get top 100 most used three word phrases in all documents

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, lucene

I have about 15,000 scraped websites with their body texts stored in an elastic search index. I need to get the top 100 most used three-word phrases being used in all these texts:

Something like this:

```
Hello there sir: 203
Big bad pony: 92
First come first: 56
[...]
```

I'm new to this. I looked into term vectors but they appear to apply to single documents. So I feel it will be a combination of term vectors and aggregation with n-gram analysis of sorts. But I have no idea how to go about implementing this. Any pointers will be helpful.

**My current mapping and settings:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "items": {
      "properties": {
        "body": {
          "type": "string",
          "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets_payloads",
          "store" : true,
          "analyzer" : "fulltext_analyzer"
         }
      }
    }
  },
  "settings" : {
    "index" : {
      "number_of_shards" : 1,
      "number_of_replicas" : 0
    },
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "fulltext_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "whitespace",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "type_as_payload"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for are called *Shingles*.  Shingles are like "word n-grams":  serial combinations of more than one term in a string.  (E.g. "We all live", "all live in", "live in a", "in a yellow", "a yellow submarine")

Take a look here:  https://www.elastic.co/blog/searching-with-shingles

Basically, you need a field with a shingle analyzer producing solely 3-term shingles:

*Elastic blog-post configuration but with:*

```
"filter_shingle":{
   "type":"shingle",
   "max_shingle_size":3,
   "min_shingle_size":3,
   "output_unigrams":"false"
}
```

The, after applying the shingle analyzer to the field in question (as in the blog post), and **reindexing your data**, you should be able to issue a query returning a simple [terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html), on your `body` field to see the top one-hundred 3-word phrases.

```
{
  "size" : 0,
  "query" : {
    "match_all" : {}
  },
  "aggs" : {
    "three-word-phrases" : {
      "terms" : {
        "field" : "body",
        "size"  : 100  
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Just one question, how do I do multiple phrase sizes with one field. Such as two-word-phrases, four-word-phrases, etc? Will I need to create an index for each analyzer?

Comment: Sort of.  Create separate fields with separate analyzers and just copy the body contents to all of them.  Then you can facet on each purpose-built shingle field.

Comment: I got it working on a single index with multiple analyzers, filters and multi-fields, like this: https://gist.github.com/HardlyMirage/448a5c8e915360f24c6bb04f5b51e785

Comment: But it takes like 6 minutes to complete the query. So will need to look into tuning this.

Comment: Indexing might take a while (depending on the size of your collection), but that query should come back in a second or so.  With 15,000 sites, I guess you could conceivably have really huge (content) sites with hundreds-of-thousands of shingles each.  If the query itself is actually that slow, try a new cluster on bigger machines (prioritize memory and local SSD storage).  You may just be swapping with too little physical memory available.