# How can I get per-document significant terms aggregations in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

In Elasticsearch, my index has fields with the following definitions:

```
"my_id": {
    "type": "keyword"
},
"titles": {
    "type": "keyword",
     "fields": {
          "fulltext": {
              "type": "text"
          }
     }
}
```

I store multiple `titles` per document (basically a string array).

Suppose I index a document with the following:

- my_id = "MH123"
- titles = [ "Star Wars: A New Hope", "Star Wars: Return of the Jedi", "Star Wars: "Empire Strikes Back" ]

I want to return `significant_terms` aggregations based on each document ID. e.g...

- Where my_id = "MH123"
- The significant terms are: "Star Wars"

I know how to do this **across** documents using a `significant_terms` aggregation. However, I can't get it to work on a child aggregation **within** a document.

I tried to create a bucket within a bucket, with the first one partitioned on the ID, and the inner one returning significant terms. The significant_terms returns an empty array.

```
{
    "aggs": {
        "titles": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "my_id"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "my_common_terms": {
                    "significant_terms": {
                        "field": "titles"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Significant terms aggs do the opposite of what you expect -- they're looking for [unusual occurrences](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-significantterms-aggregation.html), not the most common terms!

Example:

```
PUT stars
{"mappings":{"properties":{"my_id":{"type":"keyword"},"titles":{"type":"keyword","fields":{"fulltext":{"type":"text"}}}}}}
```

Then indexing a few docs with similar IDs

```
POST stars/_doc
{
  "my_id": "MH123",
  "titles": [
    "Star Wars: A New Hope",
    "Star Wars: Return of the Jedi",
    "Star Wars: \"Empire Strikes Back\""
  ]
}

POST stars/_doc
{
  "my_id": "MH124",
  "titles": [
    "Star Wars: A New Hope",
    "Star Wars: Return of the Jedi",
    "Star Wars: \"Empire Strikes Back\""
  ]
}
```

Notice how the next one has the string `uncommon terms` inside `titles`

```
POST stars/_doc
{
  "my_id": "MH125",
  "titles": [
    "uncommon terms",
    "Star Wars: A New Hope",
    "Star Wars: Return of the Jedi",
    "Star Wars: \"Empire Strikes Back\""
  ]
}
```

Now, reducing [`min_doc_count`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-significantterms-aggregation.html#_minimum_document_count_2) from the default of `3` to `1`:

```
GET stars/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "titles": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "my_id"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "my_common_terms": {
          "significant_terms": {
            "field": "titles",
            "min_doc_count": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

yielding

```
  "aggregations" : {
    "titles" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "MH123",
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "my_common_terms" : {
            "doc_count" : 1,
            "bg_count" : 3,
            "buckets" : [ ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "MH124",
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "my_common_terms" : {
            "doc_count" : 1,
            "bg_count" : 3,
            "buckets" : [ ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "MH125",
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "my_common_terms" : {
            "doc_count" : 1,
            "bg_count" : 3,
            "buckets" : [
              {
                "key" : "uncommon terms",
                "doc_count" : 1,
                "score" : 2.0,
                "bg_count" : 1
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

There are other ways of tweaking this but that's how significant terms are used.

---

What you're looking for is shingle filters and here's a [good start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18252549/how-to-find-most-used-phrases-in-elasticsearch) into those.